# internal server error on Safari only - Blueimp file upload

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, file-upload, safari, blueimp

I am using the blueimp file upload control to upload multiple high res photo (3mb-10mb each).  The site is an MVC 5 app with a Azure web app and blob storage back end. I have increased the file size limit to account for the larger images.

The following code works perfectly on any browser on a PC....but always returns a 500 internal server error for safari on a mac. unfortunately I don't have a mac with fiddler on it to get more detailed information.

The control is run inside a bootstrap modal window with the following code.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadPhoto", "PhotographerPortal", FormMethod.Post, new {id= "UploadPhoto", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    // Pass in the booking Id
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.BookingsId)

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="phototype" class="control-label"><strong>Select Photo Type:</strong></label>
        <select class="form-control" id="phototype" name="phototype">
            <option value="SamplePhoto">Sample Photo</option>
            <option value="GalleryPhoto">Gallery Photo</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="fileupload-buttonbar">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                <span>Add files...</span>
                <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple />
            </span>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                <span>Start upload</span>
            </button>

        </div>

        <span class="fileupload-process"></span>
        <div class="fileupload-progress fade">
            <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <table role="presentation" class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files"></tbody></table>
}
```

The BlueImp control is initiated with the following script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#UploadPhoto').fileupload({url: '/PhotographerPortal/UploadPhoto/'});

    $('#UploadPhoto').fileupload('option', {
        dropZone: $('#PhotoUpload'),
        maxFileSize: 10000000,
        sequentialUploads: true,
        disableImagePreview: false,
        resizeMaxWidth: 1920,
        resizeMaxHeight: 1200,
    });
</script>
```

The MVC Controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadPhoto(int BookingsId, string phototype) // optionally receive values specified with Html helper
{

    ApplicationUser user = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();

    var statuses = new List<PhotoUploadResponse>();
    for (var i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
    {
        PhotoUploadResponse uploadFileResult = new PhotoUploadResponse();

        // Call to upload the photo to Azure and the Photo DB
        var uploadResponse = CommonMethods.UploadPhotos(Request.Files[i], user, BookingsId, phototype);

        uploadFileResult.SavedFileName = uploadResponse.BlobName;
        uploadFileResult.name = uploadResponse.Name;
        uploadFileResult.size = uploadResponse.Size;

        if (uploadFileResult.error != null)
        {
            uploadFileResult.error = uploadResponse.Error;
        }
        else
        {
            uploadFileResult.url = uploadResponse.Url;
            uploadFileResult.thumbnailUrl = uploadResponse.thumbnailUrl;
        }
        statuses.Add(uploadFileResult);
    }

    var viewresult = Json(new { files = statuses });

    //for IE8 which does not accept application/json
    if (Request.Headers["Accept"] != null && !Request.Headers["Accept"].Contains("application/json"))
        viewresult.ContentType = "text/plain";

    return viewresult;
}
```

Fiddler tracked the following imput when on a PC.

[image: Fiddler Form Post]

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't suppose you've had any luck here?  I've been having the same problem for the past month or so, and it's driving me nuts.  Sounds like the same problem: the same photo uploads fine with Chrome on Windows, but fails when uploaded from Safari on a MacBook Pro.  The specific error is coming from Java's image library: "javax.imageio.IIOException: Invalid icc profile: duplicate sequence numbers".

Comment: I'm reasonably confident that the photo is getting corrupted somewhere in the upload process: when I compare hex dumps of the Chrome vs. Safari uploads, they become wildly different somewhere around byte 1B0B.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I *think* I have it -- at least, it's now working for me. I removed my settings of imageMaxWidth and imageMaxHeight, and set disableImageResize to true, and it seems to fix the problem. My best guess is that something about the resize algorithm is a bit unreliable on Safari...

Comment: Hwy Justin.  Thanks for the response. I ended up swapping to Uploadifive and increased the HttpRunTime MaxRequestLength and Execution Timepout and the RequestLImits MaxAllowedContentLength.

Comment: Also, because i am uploading to Azure, i create an azure webjob the create the thumbnails as a background task.  Minimising the tasks for the process.